# Randomly Test Cases are failing in XCUITest in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, xcuitest, uitest

I have wrote test case for XCUITest in swift, when I am running single single test cases, test cases are passing but when I am trying to run all the test cases written in the project randomly they are failing for example when I run all test at a time one test case failed and again when I run test some another test case is failing.

Comment: Do your tests share data? Do the tests depend on one another? Is there a setup dependency of some sort?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.